# VB6 List and Delete All Files in Directory

Tags: list, file, vb6, directory, delete-file

I need to grab the names of all files in a directory, I am currently using this code:

```
Dim File As String
File = Dir$(Environ("AppData") & "\*.exe")

Do While Len(File)
    MsgBox "Deleting: " & Environ("AppData") & "\" & File
Kill Environ("AppData") & "\" & File
    File = Dir$
Loop
```

This works fine, however it does not display hidden/system files, or files with any attributes other than 'normal', how can I list files no matter their attributes?

I have tried this as well, which has the same outcome:

```
Kill Environ("AppData") & "\*.*"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Dir function can take a second parameter for attributes:

```
File = Dir$(Environ("AppData") & "\*.exe", vbHidden & vbSystem)
```

You can fin more about the Dir function [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262726%28v=VS.60%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

I pretty much always use the Microsoft Scripting Runtime for file I/O from VB6.  It just does more, and it does it better and more easily.  One tiny downside is that your VB program is now dependent on the Scripting Runtime DLL (`scrrun.dll`), which you should add as a reference from within the VB6 IDE.

Here's an example that deletes all files from a folder.

```
' Note: This code is untested.

Sub Main()
    DeleteAllFilesInFolder Environ("App_Data")
End Sub

Sub DeleteAllFilesInFolder(strFolder As String)

    Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim objFolder As Scripting.Folder
    Dim objFile As Scripting.File

    Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Set objFolder = fso.GetFolder(strFolder)
    For Each objFile in objFolder.Files
        objFile.Delete force:=True
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Any alternatives without a dependency as the environment I'm creating in does not allow it.